# using stream editor with specified character positions

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to come up with a code that satisfy

1.) replace the first instance of 3 to 5.

2.) 1.) can only take place, if 3 is the first number of the digit.

for example,

38765 -> 58765

43765 will not be transformed.

so far I have,

```
sed 's/^3/5/' *.txt
```

but I just cannot figure out a way to specify the condition when position 1 == 3.

What can I do to make improvements?

Comment: The sed script in your question will do exactly what you appear to be asking for so there most be more to your question than what you've shared with us so far. Please [edit] your question to clarify your real requirements and show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed:

```
$ echo 38765 | sed 's/^3/5/'
58765
$ echo 43765 | sed 's/^3/5/'
43765
```

ie. just replace leading 3 with a 5r.

To replace 3 in the second position:

```
$ echo 33765 | sed 's/\(^.\)3/\15/'
35765
```

More generic approach:

```
$ echo 33333 | sed 's/\(^.\{3\}\)3/\15/'
33353                       ^
                            number of characters before the one to replace, 0-4
```